# Prioritizing tasks in python3 using dictionary and list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python3 where I define priorities for a particular set of tasks:

`labels_priority = {"laundry":4, "cooking":4,  "cutting_grass":3, "cleaning":0, "paint":0, "vacuuming":0, "pealing":1, "dishes":2}`

These are all the tasks in general.

Now I get an external list which shows that I have to do these tasks on a given day:
`tasks_to_do_today = [cleaning, dishes, vacuuming, cooking]`

I want to do these tasks using a for loop but my question is how do I make sure the order is correct?

I want to get a list ordered as such based on list being compared to the dictionary and priority order:

```
cleaning
vacuuming
dishes
cooking
```

Notice how "cleaning" and "vacuuming" were 0 priority so they come first. I am also noticing that python removes duplicates, that is something that I don't want. Please advise.

Also, If there is a better solution than what I'm trying to implement please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `key` argument of `list.sort` to alter what your sort order is using to determine precedence:

```
labels_priority = {"laundry":4, "cooking":4,  "cutting_grass":3, "cleaning":0,
                   "paint":0, "vacuuming":0, "pealing":1, "dishes":2}

tasks_to_do_today = ["cleaning", "dishes", "vacuuming", "cooking"]

tasks_to_do_today.sort(key=labels_priority.__getitem__)
```

If you want some sort of default priority for unrecognized tasks, you can change the `key` to a simple `lambda`:

```
tasks_to_do_today.sort(key=lambda x: labels_priority.get(x, 1000))
```

or the like, which means if the key is not found, instead of dying loudly with a `KeyError`, it silently assigns it a priority of `1000`.

This sorts that string as if it had the associated numeric value from `labels_priority`. When there's a tie, Python's sort algorithm is stable, so two strings with the same priority will appear in the same order they appeared in the original `list` (e.g. in this case, `"cleaning"` sorts before `"vacuuming"`). You could conceivably add a tie-breaker (by having the `key` function return a `tuple`, where the first element is the most important comparison, and each one after that serves as a fallback comparison), but there's no indication you need that here.

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger for your help, this worked wonderfully!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to start from this:

```
tasks_to_do_today = ["cleaning", "dishes", "vacuuming", "cooking"]
print(sorted(tasks_to_do_today, key=lambda x: labels_priority[x]))
```

Python removes duplicates in a *dictionary*, not in a *list*.

Upd. Thanks @shadowranger for clarification.

Comment: You're hand-implementing the decorate-sort-undecorate pattern (aka the Schwartzian Transform) in Python, which is kind of silly when passing a `key` argument to `sorted`/`list.sort` implements the DSU pattern much more efficiently on your behalf (the switch from `cmp` in Python 2 to `key` in Python 3 was specifically about avoiding `O(n log n)` recomputations of the key value in favor of an up-front `O(n)` decoration computing the keys once each). `sorted(tasks_to_do_today, key=lambda x: labels_priority[x])` would do exactly the same thing you've done, but significantly more efficiently.